# Android: Notify on specific value change in Firebase real-time database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Following is screenshot of my Firebase realtime database. How can I notify a user whenever the item `worker_id` is changed?

[image]

I've tried the following code, but it notifies about each type of data change. I want notification specific to change in `worker_id`:

```
private void CheckDataChange(){
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("posts");
    Query query = myRef.orderByChild("workType");
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d("Firebase","onDatachange");
    
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                try {
                    if(!ds.child("worker_id").getValue(String.class).equals("0")) {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Request accepted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }catch (Exception ex){
                    Log.e("Firebase",ex.getMessage()+ex.getCause());
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d("Firebase", databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    };

    query.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "notify a user"? Besides that, what exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo as shown in the figure, "lat", "lng","location"... whatever is changed, a Toast message is shown in the app. I want this Toast message shown only when the item "worker_id" is changed. Nothing wrong with the code,, but with the logic I used.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built into Firebase to raise an event only when the `worker_id` in your current structure changes.

The most common way to implement something like that would be to create a map mapping `ds.getKey()` to the value of `worker_id` when `onDataChange` is first called, and then comparing the value you get against that for any updates.